# How to combine two simple programs into one

Tags: java, merge

How can I combine two small programs I created?
They are conversions of Farenheit to Celsius and vice versus. When I join the two together, I clearly have double/repeating variables. Not quite sure how/what to change.

The goal is to combine the two programs so it will ask the user to choose one, (F or C) and then direct the user to input an integer to convert. Not sure if I need to create these as two objects of my class? Or how to direct a choice, maybe using Switch?

Below is one conversion used, the formula is the same just inverse.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FahrenheitToCelsius {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a degree in Fahrenheit: ");
        double fahrenheit = input.nextDouble();


        double celsius =(5.0 / 9) * (fahrenheit - 32);
        System.out.println("Fahrenheit " + fahrenheit + " is " + celsius + " in Celsius") ;
    }   
}
```

Comment: You can find multiple examples of this being done (searching something like "java temperature conversion program"). [Here's an example](https://javatutoring.com/java-convert-fahrenheit-to-celsius/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right that we can simplify the code using a single switch statement - or even an if statement in this case.

Try maybe this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String convertFrom = userInput.nextLine();
    double C, F, convertedDegrees;
    if (convertFrom.equals("F")) {
        // Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius
    } else if (convertFrom.equals("C")) {
        // Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit
        convertedDegrees = userInput.nextDouble();
        F = (convertedDegrees * 1.8) + 32;
        System.out.println(F);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid input. Please type 'C' or 'F' to indicate whether you wish to convert Celsius or Fahrenheit degrees.");
    }
}
```